# Heroku .htaccess fails with 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, heroku

I have an `.htaccess` file in my project that redirects all request to an index.php file with a query string. It works fine locally but fails when deployed to heroku. I use `apache` version `2.4.17` locally and version `2.4.20` on heroku.
Below is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: have you tried without <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: @NishantSaini yes. That fails too.

Comment: Where are you putting the rules? What does it say in the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After perusing the logs it turns out a `getallheaders()` function call was crashing the server. The `.htaccess` directive was fine. I found a workaround [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#84262)